# How to fix fonts of apps ported from Windows such as Metatrader for Mac?

Tags: windows, font, settings

I have installed Metatrader for Mac by downloading `Metatrader_4_for_Mac.dmg`. It is the most popular trading platform on Windows, and the Mac version looks exactly like Windows.

The problem with the Windows look is the font. It is absolutely dreadful to look at, and painful to read (on my non-retina display). The font is very thin, no space to breath between characters, every possible sin to be committed for a font is committed!

Is there any way to change the fonts to the Mac's readable standard?

Also remarkably I cannot quit this program with `Cmd-Q`. The only way is to quit it from the Activity Monitor!

EDIT. Here is a screenshot, the real fonts look even worse than that:
[image: http://cl.ly/image/002V2h0o1e0m/o]

Comment: What do you mean by saying "readable standard"? Are you talking about obvious difference between Mac Retina display (in this case the Display makes the difference, not the OS) and standard monitors? Can you extend your question? Can you attach two screenshots OS X vs. Windows version of Metatrader to compare the appearance and fonts smoothness.

Comment: See the edit. No retina.

Comment: It is up to the application to make the correct API calls

Comment: Did you ask the people who made the app or try their help forums?

Comment: A complete guess is that it's written in Java or something similar. Only people who can fix it are the app developers. It sure is one ugly-looking app, though… just like Windows :P